# Please, someone know how to pass double arrays by reference in functions in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, reference, double

```
int main(){
   int **mat = NULL;  //A double array
   int dim=10;
   matrizidentidad(dim,&mat); //but here we need a triple array, because in passing by reference 
   for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
           printf("\n");
           for(int j=0; j<dim; j++){
               printf(" %d ",mat[i][j]);
           }
       } 
   return 0;


   void matrizidentidad(int d, int ***ptr){
   for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
           ptr[i] = (int**)malloc(d*sizeof(int*));
           for(int j=0; j<d; j++){
               ptr[i][j] = (int*)malloc(d*sizeof(int));
           }
       }
   for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<d; j++){
               if(i==j){
                   ptr[i][j] = 1;
               }
               else{
                   ptr[i][j] = 0;
               }
           }
       }
   return;
```

The program runs, but is overruning memory, and i do not know why, but i think the error maybe be in malloc function. I try to give malloc to the triple array as well, but is the same error, overruning memory. To verify that the malloc function was the error, i use static memory, but with no better results.

Comment: Cool let me read this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not de-referencing the pointer correctly. Also, you don't want an inner loop.

```
void matrizidentidad(int d, int ***ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(d*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
        (*ptr)[i] = malloc(d*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<d; j++){
            if(i==j){
                (*ptr)[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                (*ptr)[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

You might want to simplify to:

```
int **ptr matrizidentidad(int d);
```

to avoid being a 3-star programmer.

Comment: Well, that was my idea, but mi teacher thinks different haha

Comment: Thank U very Much, it was really helpful

Comment: @FrankRenteria or [single-loop](https://pastebin.com/DQqM1By2) by exploiting calloc instead of malloc.